# How to prevent re-render when pass a dynamic import component into pure component in React

Tags: reactjs

Say, if I have a pure component and it receive a prop `component`, it's value is a function like this `() => import('../../name.tsx')`. Now I have a problem, when this pure component's parent component re-render, this pure component also re-render, how can I make this pure component not re-render when it's parent re-renders.

Answer (score 1):

use `React.memo` on the child you don't want to re-render. [more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

Comment: But React.memo is for function component, the pure component is a class component.

Comment: it shourl work with those 2 https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13937 :)

Comment: After add React.memo, the pure component still re-render. It seems that it does not work. @Henri De Bel

Comment: try adding a should component update like function to make sure it does not re render => https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-swirles-gx2je?file=/src/components/function/TestFunc.js

Comment: Thank you. I great tip. I solve my problem. When i use dynamic imports and use router.push with shallow:true → also re-render (flickr). So when i use useMemo problem is gone. Thanks again.